# iPhone Bookmarks and Session variables (User has to log in twice)

Tags: iphone, session, bookmarks, homescreen

I'm creating a web application meant to be viewed by iPhones, Blackberrys etc. My problem is that, when an iPhone user adds a link to the app on their home screen, they have to log in twice.

The cycle goes like this:

1. User bookmarks the app's homepage
2. User later goes to the homepage
3. They are brought first to the log in screen
4. After logging in, they are taken to the app's homepage
5. As soon as they click a link, Safari opens a new window in which they are brought to the log in page again
6. After logging in this time, everything works as normal

It seems like a problem with Session variables, though I can't seem to find any sort of elegant solution for it.

Also, the server is running ColdFusion.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to drop a cookie when the user first logs in?